# docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:

Tags: macos, docker

Even though this question might look like a duplicate one, i seem to be having a peculiar problem here.

**Scenario 1:The project folder in the /users directory**

I get the below error when i tried to start my docker image:

docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:

`The path /users/myUserName/myApp/backend/build/pacts is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.`

The exact same command passed a few days back and has suddenly stopped working

**Scenario 2: The project folder is in the /Documents folder**

The docker run command which threw the same error as Scenario 1 now somehow seems to work fine.

The docker preferences has /Users in the list of shared directories and still doesnt work.
(Image attached)
[Docker preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn4RW.png)

Macos version : Mojave(10.14.6)

Note: Whenever the docker run command throws the error in Scenario 1, simply shifting the project to a new location (like /Downloads) seems to work fine.Even though this fixes the issue temporarily, i am curious to know why this error occurs even though the default preferences are as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is case sensitive. The paths `/users/myUserName/myApp/backend/build/pacts` and `/Users/myUserName/myApp/backend/build/pacts` are different inside of docker while MacOS treats them as the same.

To fix, you likely need to `cd /Users/myUserName/myApp/` before running your command.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!!.
Seeing your answer i just realized i had set up an alias to jump directly to my project folder, which i changed it per your answer and it works fine now.
Thanks a ton once again.